# JPA Repository: javax.persistence.NonUniqueResultException: result returns more than one elements

Tags: java, jpa, spring-data-jpa

Using the below code I am unable to get the results of my query.  Whether I use `Map<ContentType...` or `Map<String...` I get the same error: javax.persistence.NonUniqueResultException: result returns more than one elements

It seems like JPA should be able to handle multiple rows in Repositories.  I've looked around for other annotations that I might just be missing and am having a hard time coming up with results.

Any suggestions on what I should do to resolve this?

```
@Transactional
public interface ContentRepository extends JpaRepository<Content,Integer>{

    ....

    @Query(nativeQuery=true, value="SELECT content_type, COUNT(*) AS myColumn FROM dbo.content GROUP BY content_type")
    Map<ContentType, Integer> getContentCountByType();

}
```

Comment: For starters, this is not just JPA, it looks like Spring Data JPA.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It appears that the problem was that `Map<ContentType, Integer>` does not have a promise of a unique index, so JPA doesn't like mapping to it.  By using `List<Map<ContentType, Integer>>` instead, it works great!

Answer (score 0):

**Try this it works**

**keep your model in list**

```
@RequestMapping(value="/deleteDriver/{id}" , method=RequestMethod.POST)
public ResponseEntity<Object> deleteDriver(@PathVariable("id") Integer id)
{
    List<Driver> delete_driver=adminService.getDriverById(id);
    Map<String,Object> response=new HashMap<>();


    if(delete_driver==null)
    {
        response.put("status", "Failure");
        return new ResponseEntity<Object>(response,HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT);
    }
    else
    {
        response.put("status", "Success");
        adminService.delete(delete_driver);
        return new ResponseEntity<Object>(response,HttpStatus.OK);
    }

}
```

> then in your repository

```
@Override
public void delete(List<Driver> delete_driver) {

    driverRepository.delete(delete_driver);
}
```

Comment: This is an almost 100% code-only answer. It tends to increase the misunderstanding that StackOverflow is a free code-writing service. It might be more appreciated, if you extend it with some explanation of how and why your proposal helps with the probklem.