# How can I return date and count of records for that date using spring data jpa?

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I want to return event count by date.Below is my code

```
@Query(value = "select DATE(e.startTime) as day,count(distinct e.id) as eventCount from events e " +
            "where e.clientId=:clientId and e.startTime>=:firstDay and e.startTime<=:lastDay group by DATE(e.startTime)",nativeQuery = true)
    Map<Integer, Integer> getClientEventsCountByDay(@Param(value = "clientId") Integer clientId,
                                                    @Param(value = "firstDay") String firstDay,
                                                    @Param(value = "lastDay") String lastDay);
```

Input is clientId=2510,firstDay=2019-01-01,lastDay=2019-01-31

This query is throwing below error

> Caused by:
>   org.springframework.dao.IncorrectResultSizeDataAccessException: result
>   returns more than one elements; nested exception is
>   javax.persistence.NonUniqueResultException: result returns more than
>   one elements

However this query is working fine when running directly on db.
[image]

Comment: This might help you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12270991/jpa-repository-javax-persistence-nonuniqueresultexception-result-returns-more.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JPA Repository: javax.persistence.NonUniqueResultException: result returns more than one elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12270991/jpa-repository-javax-persistence-nonuniqueresultexception-result-returns-more)

Comment: My goal is to return date,count as key value as shown in attached image in question.If I am taking list of map then for each day I am having a map that is unnecessary.Could you suggest some other approach to achieve this? End goal is to return day and count as key value.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing to this

```
List<Map<Integer, Integer>> getClientEventsCountByDay(@Param(value = "clientId") Integer clientId,
                                                @Param(value = "firstDay") String firstDay,
                                                @Param(value = "lastDay") String lastDay);
```

Comment: My goal is to return date,count as key value as shown in attached image in question.If I am taking list of map then for each day I am having a map that is unnecessary.Could you suggest some other approach to achieve this?
End goal is to return day and count as key value.